# When I type "python --version" in cmd, nothing happens

Tags: python, windows

I uninstalled Python from my Windows machine, now when I type `python` in `cmd`, I should get an error but [I don’t](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BSo1.jpg).

Does that mean that I still have Python installed?

Take a look:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.836]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\h2001>python

C:\Users\h2001>python --version

C:\Users\h2001>python3

C:\Users\h2001>python33
'python33' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\h2001>python2
'python2' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Sometimes when you don't have Python, it even takes you to the Microsoft Store. Nothing to worry about.